# What is the difference between the various KL-divergence implementations in TensorFlow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, statistics, tensorflow-probability

While constructing a Variational Autoencoder in TensorFlow, I came across various implementations of Kullback–Leibler divergence:

1. `tfp.distributions.kl_divergence`, which implements the exact KL-divergence measure.
2. `tfp.layers.KLDivergenceAddLoss`, which uses a Monte Carlo approximation.
3. `tfp.layers.KLDivergenceRegularizer`, which seems similar in calculation and use.
4. `tf.keras.losses.KLDivergence`, which uses the formula `y_true * log(y_true / y_pred)`.

I use `tfp.distribution`s to model both the prior and the posterior, so any of the above implementations are compatible. However, although I assume that (2) and (3) are identical, I primarily wonder whether these are comparable to (4).

Any knowledge on this matter is appreciated!